# Adding a simple mix() destroys the framerate

Tags: android, opengl-es, shaders, performance

I have a very simple shader and added linear fog via mix like this:

```
finalColor = mix(finalColor, vec3(0.5, 0.8, 0.95), vUVoutAndViewZ.z);
```

Note that the view Z distance is in the variable that also contains the UV coordinates, so the fog didn't even add a new interpolator.

Still, this one innocuous line brought the framerate on the OG Droid with the Power SGX chipset from 33fps to 22fps. Even the HTC Evo with the Adreno 200 GPU stays under 30fps. (The Adreno 205 is at a constant 60fps, but that thing is a beast).

The fragment shader itself is primitive (all values are hard-coded since it's a test shader):

```
precision mediump float;
varying mediump vec3 vUVoutAndViewZ;
varying lowp vec3 vNormalOut;

uniform lowp sampler2D diffuse;


void main() {
    lowp vec3 normal = vNormalOut;

    // Lighting
    lowp vec3 lightDir = vec3(0.5, 0.3, 0.5);
    lowp vec3 light = vec3(dot(normal, lightDir));

    lowp vec3 diffuse = texture2D(diffuse, vUVoutAndViewZ.xy).rgb;

    lowp vec3 finalColor = diffuse * light;

    // Fog
    finalColor = mix(finalColor, vec3(0.5, 0.8, 0.95), vUVoutAndViewZ.z);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(finalColor.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

I added the lowp/mediump declarations later (which added about 2fps), it works just as bad without them.

I refuse to believe that the PowerVR chipset is so weak that it can't handle a simple shader like this. There must be something stupid in this shader (like something implicitly swizzling a lowp register) that just completely messes up the unit.

**ANSWER and EDIT:**

Ellis has some fantastic information in the answer and the subsequent comments. In this particular case, it seems that mix() is flat-out broken. It brought the shader to 12 cycles (from 4) and 4 GPRs (from 2). I got back to 29fps by using this code instead:

```
lowp vec3 fogDiff = vec3(0.5, 0.8, 0.95) - finalColor;
fogDiff *= vUVoutAndViewZ.z;
finalColor += fogDiff;
```

Comment: Do you know that fog is not linear with depth? If you are not afraid of adding pow function to the shader, i think you should try to make it more realistic ;)

Comment: @notabene: I'm aware of that, but since this post is about how a simple `mix()` killed the framerate, I wasn't too inclined to throw in a `pow` to finish it off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Response from EboMike computed with PVRUniSCo Editor: mix() brings the shader from 4 cycles to 12 cycles** (PowerVR).

The PowerVR 530/535 is very slow. Andreno 200 and PowerVR 530/535 are first GPU generation (OpenGL ES 2.x) for hdpi resolution. You can't redraw a full screen at 60FPS with a simple texture.

I wrote GPUBench to test shaders performance and it is very bad on these GPU. The second generation (Andreno 205, Powervr 540) is far better.

Today, i try to minimize Fragment shader with one or two operations. You can try to [optimize](http://aras-p.info/blog/2010/09/29/glsl-optimizer/) your shader because GLSL compilers are bad (on mobile platform).

Note: for powervr gpu, read this [document](http://www.imgtec.net/factsheets/SDK/POWERVR%20SGX.OpenGL%20ES%202.0%20Application%20Development%20Recommendations.1.1f.External.pdf). PVRUniSCo Editor can compute cycles used in shaders.

My toughts:

- The Droid GPU is slower than Andreno 200 because of fillrate
- 30 FPS for Andreno 200 is good
- 20 FPS for Droid is good
- You can render your scene in a smaller FBO and draw it on a screen (but FBO switch is costly)
- Fragment shaders must be very short.

Comment: You're breaking my heart! What about the HTC Evo? Wouldn't the Adreno 200 at least be able to handle that? Even for a weak GPU, that seems unreasonably pathetic.

Comment: My goal is 30fps at least for the Droid and EVO. I vaguely remember games like Backbreaker that SEEM to look quite nice (been a while since I've seen it, I might be wrong). What's the secret here? I have no overdraw, I barely use alpha blending, and this shader is primitive. Do you have any idea? (Btw, will accept answer in a few hours, don't worry :) )

Comment: 30 FPS for Droid or EVO is very difficult. These GPU have very low fillrate.

Comment: I don't know anything about mobile graphics chipsets, but I can't help noticing that you didn't explain the most interesting part. Why a single line drops performance so dramatically? Is it really slow mix operation?

Comment: This is one of the cases where I wish I could upvote an answer twice.

Comment: @Nevermind: I should let Ellis answer, but in general, everything becomes a bottleneck. Each instruction needs to be executed for each pixel, and since mix will probably translate into at least two pixel shader instructions, this adds up quickly if your GPU is slow. Then, of course, there COULD be bottlenecks if you use too many GPRs, which stall out your shader unit because it can't parallelize as well.

Comment: @Ellis: Is there a way to see the actual compiled shader fragment code? I'm writing GLSL code, but I'd love to see what the compiler makes out of it.

Comment: I haven't tried it but you can look "PVRUniSCo Editor" for GLSL instruction cycles.

Comment: The editor is fantastic. I wish I could upvote your answer three times...

Comment: According to the editor, that mix() brings the shader from 4 cycles to 12 cycles, and twice as many GPRs. Wow.

Comment: @Ellis: This tool is absolutely brilliant. See the edit to my original question, I got it back to 29fps by simply changing the mix() to something else. Does mix() internally saturate, or why is it so ridiculously slow?

Comment: @EboMike mix() is not very used on mobile platform, so i think there is no optimization done (driver or software).

Comment: I would have thought even the most primitive compiler would convert `d=mix(a,b,c)` into `d+=(b-a)*c`. Oh well, you know what they say - if you want to get the job done right, you have to do it yourself. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Btw, since you're Mr. Unity, feel free to double-check my findings. I may have missed something. Also, I suspect that the problem could be that mix() will internally always use mediump (or worse) for the computations. If I use a mediump for `fogDiff` in the above example, I get back to the same performance numbers I had with `mix()`.